# The months shown on the reputation chart are all next to each other, no spaces

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-graph

I was just checking on my account since I saw an e-mail notifying me on the change in reputation on questions, and I noticed this:

[image: febmayaugnov picture]

I recognize that this is a bug, and I want to shed light onto it, but I am also wondering how this might have occurred.

Comment: Which browser is this on?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Microsoft Edge; I assume it works on Chrome because I use a browser that was made by the makers of Chrome, but I don't know there either

Comment: @F1r3Sp33d Which version of Edge? Pre-Chrome or post-Chrome?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Microsoft Edge v. 44.18362.449.0 and post-Chrome I think